# UDP response received after timeout

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, timeout

We have an UDP client that communicates against a server.

The server gives a single response on each request.

The client sends a request, and waits 5 seconds for the response.

If the server's response was not received by 5 seconds - the client assumes that the packet was lost in the network (this is UDP...), writes a report to a log, and sends the next request.

But, sometimes we have any delay in the network, and the server's response comes after 5 seconds.

Let's describe the scenario:

The client sent a packet named "X".

The timeout of 5 seconds expired, and the client reports that "X" is a lost packet.

The client sent another packet named "Y".

The server's response on "X" comes now to the client.

The client sees that the response is not compatible to the request, and report it to the log.

The client sent another packet named "Z".

The server's response on "Y" comes now to the client.

The client sees that the response is not compatible to the request, and report it to the log.

And this is an infinity loop!

What can we do?

Comment: Are you saying that the client stops waiting for the real reply, (so it does does not wait the full 5 seconds) if it gets a reply that is inconsistent with the most recent request ?

Comment: rarely the processing takes 6 seconds or more (i cannot identify it).

Comment: Ok, but what about the question I asked ? Does your client send a new request immediately after it gets the unexpected reply ?

Comment: Yes. the wrong answer can be a result of any other mistake/error.

Comment: Then don't have the client send a new request immediately after receiving the invalid reply. Instead have it throw away the invalid reply, and wait for the remaining time of the 5 second timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Many UDP-based protocols include an identifier to indicate which request a given response belongs to.  The client chooses the identifier and sends it to the server as part of the request, and then the server echoes it back in the response.  This allows the client to match responses to requests, especially in situations like the one you describe.  If the client received the response to `X` after having moved on, it would be able to simply ignore that response.

Comment: Yeah - AKA 'sequence numbers' :)